# Sqoop - Postgres No Conecction Parameters Specified

Tags: postgresql, sqoop

I am trying to connect to Postgres DB using Sqoop (the end goal is to import tables directly into HDFS), however I am facing the issue below.

`sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:postgresql://<server_name>:5432/aae_data --username my_username -P --verbose`

> Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.1-1.cdh5.9.1.p2260.2452/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>   18/04/24 00:13:40 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.9.1
>   18/04/24 00:13:40 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
>   Enter password:
>   18/04/24 00:13:44 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   18/04/24 00:13:44 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   18/04/24 00:13:44 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:postgresql:
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.PostgresqlManager@56a6d5a6
>   18/04/24 00:13:45 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Do I need to specify a connection manager? If yes, how do I pass the jar file?

Thank You.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.` is normal output (see [sources](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/SqlManager.java#L898-L899))

Comment: hey, I am having a similar output... I guess also for @akakak the 'problem' is that we are providing a passw, so we do not expect that message...